# Convert Python List to JSON Separate Objects

Tags: python, json, string

I have a l̶i̶s̶t̶ string in Python

`[Volume:vol-XXXXXXXX, Volume:vol-YYYYYYYY]`

that I want to change to into JSON. The final result should be

`{ volumes: ["Volume:vol-XXXXXXXX", "Volume:vol-YYYYYYYY"] };`

I tried using `json.dumps` after changing it to a dict but for some reason it didn't work. How do I do something like this?

---

WHOOPS! The "list" I was talking about was actually a string :|. Guess I learned my lesson with a downvote storm!

Comment: You most certainly do not have this as a list:  `[Volume:vol-XXXXXXXX, Volume:vol-YYYYYYYY]`.  Paste your actual code, please, so we can help you.

Comment: What is Volume:vol-XXXXXXXX? A string, a variable?

Comment: Why did this get down-voted so heavily?

Comment: While I can't speak for the others, my downvote is because you did not paste your actual code.  That would produce a syntax error in both Python 2 and 3.  Until you provide us what you _actually wrote_, we can't help you improve it.

Comment: @user3822146: probably because the code you're giving is bad. You can't have a colon inside of a list like that. Please give more information about what you've tried, including actual code.

Comment: Oh, I see. My problem is that I'm retrieving "volumes" from AWS which actually returns a list like that in Python.

Comment: @user3822146: No it doesn't. There is no such thing as a list like that in Python. Here's how to fix it: When you get the response from AWS, `print(repr(response))`, then copy and paste that into your question. If your question actually makes sense, it will get reopened (the early downvotes often don't go away, but people may upvote to compensate) and you'll get a useful answer.

Comment: @user3822146 - If you'd printed the `repr` as suggested by abarnert you'd see that what you actually have is a string, not a list.  That's a key piece of information.  What you have there needs to be parsed somehow.  It's fine as a string, but it is not a list, and it cannot be evaluated directly as a list.  You need to rethink what you're attempting to accomplish because the data you have does _not_ lend itself to your desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
volumes = ["Volume:vol-XXXXXXXX", "Volume:vol-YYYYYYYY"]

json.dumps({
  "volumes": volumes
})
```